# how to parse a column in mysql table like " <14-abc>;<8-def>;

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

how to parse a column in mysql table like  `<14-abc>;<8-def>;`
 as:

```
abc =14
def = 8
```

abc store value 14 and def stores values 8  and have multiple entries.

So need to store like array or list that should be able to access and 
process the parsed data later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any parser that support this syntax, so you could write your own parser for something so trivial. Here's an example, not tested:

```
$row = ' <14-abc>;<8-def>; ';

$output = Array();
$entries = explode(';', $row);              //Split the row by every ';' delimiter
foreach ($entries as $item) {               //For each entries
    if (!empty($item)) {                    //Make sure the item isn't empty (last entry might be)
        $item = str_replace(' ','',$item);  //Remove useless char
        $item = str_replace('<','',$item);  //Remove useless char
        $item = str_replace('>','',$item);  //Remove useless char
        $params = explode('-', $item);      //Again, subsplit the key and the value from the item
        $output[$params[1]] = $params[0];   //Push them into an array
    }
}
```

Then you can use your awesome array like so:

```
foreach ($output as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key.'='.$value;
}
```

The input is a `$row` string, the output is a `$output` array. You can even wrap it into a function ;)

Comment: If you're testing the solution, I just updated it. It looks fine, as long as the data is in the same format you said.

Comment: Hi Alex ,  Yes the data is in the same format. It works. Thanx a lot.

Comment: What if we have multiple entries like these. And later on we want to calculate avg for each key like avg for all 'abc' key value pair  and same for 'def'.

Comment: Just put the entire code into your mysql loop. Again it'll work as long as `$row` is defined with the proper format.

Comment: Ahh.. oki.. thanx a tonnes for help. :)

Comment: The parser above results in key value pair array as abc = 14        def =8   How can this be put directly in a sql DB table having two columns String And Value for key and value respectively.

Comment: instead of `echo()`ing them, you could do `mysql_query('INSERT INTO tablename("String","Value") VALUES("'.$key.'",'.$value.')');`

Comment: Maybe the types of your columns arn't correct, because it should work. I mean, I don't have your project in front of me, you can double-check everything, but it should in theory, work.

Comment: Hm.. May be I was doing something wrong. " INSERT INTO tablename(`String`, `Value`) VALUES ('$key','$value'); " works fine now.    Thanx a lot.

Answer (score -1):

```
?php

function parser($row)
{
$output = Array();

$entries = explode(';', $row);       //Split the row by every ';' delimiter
foreach ($entries as $item) {                   //For each entries
    if (!empty($item)) {                        //Make sure the item isn't empty (last entry might be)
        $item = str_replace(' ','',$item);      //Remove extra char
        $item = str_replace('<','',$item);      //Remove extra char
        $item = str_replace('>','',$item);      //Remove extra char
        $params = explode('-', $item);          //Again, subsplit the key and the value from the item
        $output[$params[1]] = $params[0];       //Push them into an array
    }
}
foreach ($output as $key=>$value) {

    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO `tablename`(`column name`, `column name`) VALUES ('$key','$value')";
    mysql_query($sql1); 

    }
}
?>
```

This does all the work.. Defines parser function , parses data and inserts the result in DB